# PreferenceScreen crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, android-preferences

I made a PreferenceScreen using **res/xml/preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <preferencecategory 

     android:title="@string/pref_lang_setting">

        <listpreference 
            android:key="preflang" 
            android:entries="@array/lang_select_array" 
            android:summary="@string/pref_lang_summary"  
            android:title="@string/pref_lang"
            android:entryValues="@array/lang_select_Values"
            >

        </listpreference>

    </preferencecategory>

</preferenceScreen>
```

The PreferencesActivity looks like this:

```
package com.example.mypackage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;


public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);  // deprecated
    }

}
```

And this is called from another Activity by using:

```
case R.id.action_settings:
             Intent i = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);  
             // startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SETTINGS);
        break;
```

When I click to load the PreferencesActivity, the application crashes and I get this error:

> > 05-18 11:39:15.882: W/System.err(29994): 
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mypackage/com.example.mypackage.PreferencesActivity}:
> >      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class preferenceScreen

I have searched a lot, but the problem remains.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One problem I noticed is that `ListPreference` isn't capitalized correctly.  Neither is `PreferenceCategory` or `PreferenceScreen`.  Look here for a complete example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Comment: Chill, dude.  We apparantly answered at the same time, I updated my response to include the other two items as well.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. So I updated my comment. Removing it in 3... 2...  1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the proper character casing for `PreferenceScreen`, `PreferenceCategory` and `ListPreference`

Comment: yep. this was the problem. Pretty silly on my part. But I thought that eclipse would show some kind of build error:( Thanks though.

Comment: Weird that Lint didn't notify that. Check out your Lint settings.

Comment: Probably, some warning is disabled.